# Initiating object creation without ToolButton using MapBasic

Tags: mapbasic

Is it possible to have a subroutine in MapBasic that will initiate object creation, in same way as if you clicked Spatial->Insert->Polyline for example.

I know I can create custom ToolButton and set DrawMode, but I have C# form and one of button is meant to initiate polygon creation. I have looked deeply in MapBasic Reference and User Guide, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a ToolButton control to the ribbon that has the right properties such as drawmode and cursor.

In your dialog, you can then use SetCurrentCustomTool to activate your tool.